# probability vs. trials: a special case where the number of draws is not constant

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have 3 cards of color heart one of them is Ace AND one other card of type spade to make all together 4 cards

the success is when I draw Ace heart

a player must draw the Ace heart within a number of trials.

it counts as a trial if a heart card is drawn otherwise, it does not count as a trial (if I draw the spade card)

I draw a card at one time. depending on the type of the card we increment the number of trials by  1 or by 0

now I know that the probability to draw the Ace heart is 1 if I am allowed to have maximum of three trials. however, I could not write this in a neat probabilistic way.

PS: my original problem is 67 cards one of them is my card of interest plus 13 cards that do not count as a trial if I pull them.

it would be more helpful form me if I could build a table for permitted trials vs probability
regards

Comment: Have you tried thinking about the draws as a sequence of cards? Then it should answer your first question without any problem, because any of these sequences contains exactly three cards of type heart. Hence, you will never have more than three trials.

Comment: yes but when I add the probabiliteis I do not get 1:        

exactly 1 trial + exactly 2 trials + exactly3 trials should be 1

Comment: Are you familiar with the [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)?

Comment: yes and I wanted to exploit it but I could not define the probability of success p and the probability of failure 1-p